# Powershell try block doesn't release file handle for catch block

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, webclient

I'm writing a script that tries to download a file with two file-download methods. 
 I'm not going to go into great details, but the resulting function looks something like this:

```
function Download-FileRobust($url, $targetFile) {
    try {
        Download-File $url $targetFile
    }
    catch {
        Download-FileWget $url $targetFile
    }
}
```

When the `Download-File` function fails, PowerShell doesn't loosen the handle on the created file at location `$targetFile`, and `Download-FileWget` can't write to that location.

I'm used to Python, so it took me quite a while to figure out the problem.

The source-code for the other two functions are as follows:

```
function Download-FileWget($url, $targetFile){
    $wgetDir = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:userprofile\Downloads\wget*win32").FullName
    if($env:Path -notlike "*$wgetDir*"){
        $env:Path = "$wgetDir;$env:Path"
    }
    Invoke-Expression "wget '$url' -O '$targetFile'"
}

function Download-File($url, $targetFile){
   $uri = New-Object "System.Uri" "$url"
   $request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($uri)
   $request.set_Timeout(15000) #15 second timeout
   $response = $request.GetResponse()
   $totalLength = [System.Math]::Floor($response.get_ContentLength()/1024)
   $responseStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
   $targetStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $targetFile, Create
   $buffer = new-object byte[] 10KB
   $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.length)
   $downloadedBytes = $count

   while ($count -gt 0){
       $targetStream.Write($buffer, 0, $count)
       $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.length)
       $downloadedBytes = $downloadedBytes + $count
       Write-Progress -activity "Downloading file '$($url.split('/') | Select -Last 1)'" -status "Downloaded ($([System.Math]::Floor($downloadedBytes/1024))K of $($totalLength)K): " -PercentComplete ((([System.Math]::Floor($downloadedBytes/1024)) / $totalLength)  * 100)

   }
   Write-Progress -activity "Finished downloading file '$($url.split('/') | Select -Last 1)'"
   $targetStream.Flush()
   $targetStream.Close()
   $targetStream.Dispose()
   $responseStream.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: What version of powershell are you on?

Comment: I'm on version 2.0. Upgrading is not an option. I'm writing a script that needs to run on old windows 7 machines out of the box.

Comment: Please post the contents of your `Download-File` and `Download-FileWget`

Comment: *Powershell doesn't loosen the handle on the created file at location `$targetFile`* It is not PowerShell responsibility to do that. `Download-File` responsible for closing handles, which it no more plan to use.

Comment: I've added the other two functions. I must probably somehow at the `$response = $request.GetResponse()` line in `Download-File` do an early termination of the function if no response is returned. At that point the target file hasn't been opened yet.

Comment: So it seems my question now boils down to: how do you check if `$request.GetResponse()` is successful? I can't seem to pass the `-ErrorVariable` to the function. And do you then just let the function fail at that point via something like `throw "Unable to download file $url"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `Download-File` function you never actually do anything to ensure the `$targetStream` is properly flushed and disposed of. You need to wrap the streams in a `try/catch/finally` blocks:

```
function Download-File {
    param([string]$url, [string]$targetFile)

    $uri = New-Object "System.Uri" "$url"
    $request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($uri)
    $request.set_Timeout(15000) #15 second timeout
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $totalLength = [System.Math]::Floor($response.get_ContentLength()/1024)
    $responseStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
    try {
        $targetStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $targetFile, Create
        try {
            $buffer = new-object byte[] 10KB
            $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.length)
            $downloadedBytes = $count

            while ($count -gt 0){
                $targetStream.Write($buffer, 0, $count)
                $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.length)
                $downloadedBytes = $downloadedBytes + $count
                Write-Progress -activity "Downloading file '$($url.split('/') | Select -Last 1)'" -status "Downloaded ($([System.Math]::Floor($downloadedBytes/1024))K of $($totalLength)K): " -PercentComplete ((([System.Math]::Floor($downloadedBytes/1024)) / $totalLength)  * 100)

            }
            Write-Progress -activity "Finished downloading file '$($url.split('/') | Select -Last 1)'"
        }
        catch {
            throw
        }
        finally {
            if($targetStream){
                $targetStream.Flush()
                $targetStream.Close()
                $targetStream.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        throw
    }
    finally {
        $responseStream.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I needed!